# SwiftUI: How to create LazyGrid with equal number of rows and columns?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a grid in `SwiftUI 2` using the new primitives `LazyVGrid`/`LazyHGrid`.

My goal is to create a grid with the following properties:

- Each cell has the same width as height (basically a square)
- The grid has an equal number of rows and columns (Columns = Rows)
- The content should not be scrollable and always fit the size of my view/screen.

Here's a video with the expected results. This was achieved by a custom `Grid` object that uses `GeometryReader`.

[image]

I've tried using `.contentMode(1, .fit)` to restrain the `LazyVGrid` to a 1:1 ratio but it doesn't seem to work. The red background represents the frame of the Grid which is not the expected behaviour.

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 32), spacing: 0)], spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
        Rectangle()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .border(Color.black)
    }
}
.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
.background(Color.red)
```

[image: Grid Attempt]

I have also tried using `GeometryReader` to fix the size of the `LazyVGrid`, but it still didn't work. Any other ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Your code is missing the end of the first line. Presumably you want a grid of 32 x 32 white squares, all on screen at the same time? No scrolling?

Comment: What attached screenshot means? It does not look like what you try to achieve.

Comment: @Magnas I would like to create a grid with 100 white squares that fits the size of the screen, without scrolling.

Comment: @Asperi I've updated my question. I hope it is more clearer now. The screenshot represents my attempt at making a grid with 100 squares that should fit the screen nicely, as in the example shown above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After seeing [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087382/7897036)'s solution above, I've managed to solve the final piece of the puzzle. Here's the code:

```
var body: some View {
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 4, maximum: 48), spacing: 0), count: 10)

    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .border(Color.black)
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    .background(Color.red)
}
```

[image: Final Product]

Answer (score 8):

Try the following (tested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14, no big-sur)

```
struct TestGridFitView: View {
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 32), spacing: 0), count: 10)
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    .border(Color.black)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving an infinity max width? Like this:

```
    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 32), spacing: 0)], spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
        Rectangle()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .border(Color.black)
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(Color.red)
```

Comment: This does not work - https://imgur.com/a/VKvSpaU. I don't understand how you could achieve a grid with the same amount of rows as columns with your implementation.